# God and angels in Job 4:18 and 15:15

Tags: job, angels

Two related verses in Job seem to place God in an unexpected relationship with his angels:

> 'He puts no trust even in His servants; And against His angels He
>   charges error.
>
> Job 4:18 (NASB)

Is the verse telling us that good angels who did not fall are not good enough.

> Behold, God puts no trust in his holy ones, and the heavens are not
>   pure in his sight;
>
> Job 15:15 (ESV)

Why does God have no trust to his angels? Why are the heavens not pure in God's sight?

Comment: The assumption is that the verse is referring to good angels as opposed to bad angels (cp. [2 Pet. 2:4](https://www.blueletterbible.org/kjv/2pe/2/4/t_conc_1158004)).

Comment: @H3br3wHamm3r81, If it is about fallen angels, then, why did it call them 'his servants' and 'his angels' ?

Comment: Because He created them, and therefore, they are still His servants and His angels. God still uses them for His purposes. Is not Satan a fallen angel, and yet God uses him in that very book to test Job, right?

Comment: @H3br3wHamm3r81, Exactly.

Comment: Parallel question on the theology at Christianity.SE: [Are angels in heaven still able to sin?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/44083/are-angels-in-heaven-still-able-to-sin)

Comment: Could it possibly be hyperbole used to compare God's holiness with creation, making God out to be that much better than that which is already good?

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question would seem quite simple.

Since Job 4:1 identifies the speaker whose statement is found at Job 4:18, as Eliphaz:

> Then Eliphaz the Temanite answered and said,

and Job 15:1 identifies the speaker whose statement appears at job 15:15, as the same:

> Then answered Eliphaz the Temanite, and said,

and God says to that man at the conclusion of the story:

> ... My wrath is kindled against thee, and against thy two friends: for ye have not spoken of me the thing that is right, as my servant Job hath.
>   -- Job 42:7 (KJV)

then a prudent reader would suspect the views of Eliphaz are flawed.

### Conclusion

One can trust the words of Eliphaz in regard to God's angels and the heavens, or one can trust the words of God who said Eliphaz had "*not spoken of me the thing that is right*"?

As for me, I stand with God.

Comment: "*The answer to your question would seem quite simple.*" No, it is not. Oversimplifying that "*the views of Eliphaz are flawed*" is a mistake. That generalization inevitably encompasses Eliphaz's other views such as "*[God] doeth great things [...]; marvellous things without number*", Job 5:8-9, thereby leading to a multitude of contradictions. Moreover, 4:18 is not even Eliphaz's view, but his quote of the spirit, 4:15. If we were to disqualify everything that Eliphaz, Bildad, and Zophar said merely by virtue of 42:7, we would be essentially suppressing and mutilating much of the Book of Job.

Comment: So, you'd rather trust Eliphaz' words concerning God, than trust God's words concerning Eliphaz. That is your prerogative.

Comment: You are misinterpreting and misapplying Job 42:7 by using it as your "prudent" method for discarding anything Eliphaz said. The sense of 42:7 is that, among Eliphaz's statements, he missed the specific "thing" God expected him to assert. By striking Eliphaz's every view as flawed, you impliedly distrust his words concerning God at 5:8-9! The substantial overlap between (1)Eliphaz's words concerning God, and (2)God's speech puts you in the untenable position of having to trust something because God said it and simultaneously distrust the exact same idea because "flawed" Eliphaz asserted it too.

Comment: @IñakiViggers I am not implying anything about Eliphaz' words other than those quoted by the OP. I really don't see anything profitable being born of further discussion of the matter.

Comment: Exactly, the OP asked about 4:18, and a bare allusion to 42:7 does not address the core of her question whatsoever. By that token, 42:7 could be (mis-)applied to each and every question of that type: If/when another user asks "*why did Bildad say that 'xyz' in Job n1:n2?*", answering that "*well, according to 42:7 he is wrong after all, so it is prudent for us to suspect that his views are flawed*" eludes the user's inquiry altogether.

Comment: @IñakiViggers, I thinks Enegue's answer is in the right direction. OP assumes that Eliphaz's words carry the authority of Holy Spirit, which is terriably bad assumption according to God in Job 42:7 undermining the premise of the question. However, as you have pointed out, sometimes Eliphaz echos scripture. So the answer is pretty simple. Only count as valid Enegue's words that reflect truth already revealed in scripture. Beyond that, we shouldn't consider true what scripture doesn't confirm regarding Eliphaz words.

Comment: @Austin "*Only count as valid Enegue's words that reflect truth already revealed in scripture.*" (You mean *Eliphaz's* words, right?) That leads to the outcome I previously pointed out: suppressing or mutilating of much of the Book of Job. By the same token, it reduces the Bible to a net of redundancies and circular references that does not really enlighten us on the fundamental problems we sooner or later face.

Comment: @IñakiViggers, Yes I meant Eliphaz. Thank you. If the devil is a liar then we only accept the devil's words as true to the extent that they are confirmed by higher authority. If Eliphaz misrepresents God, according to God, then we can only count his word's as true to the extent that they are confirmed by a higher authority. There is no need to do this for the entire Bible. That would be a strawman. This principle only applies to those whose truthfulness has been thoroughly discredited by the Bible.

Comment: @Austin "*This principle only applies to those whose truthfulness has been thoroughly discredited by the Bible.*" I can't think of a passage where the Bible discredits the Eliphaz's assertions the OP brought up. If anything, Eliphaz's statement "*against His angels He charges error*" (4:18) is evidenced in 2:3 (KJV) where God implies that Satan's prediction about Job was mistaken. Furthermore, reading into God's twofold trust in Satan a "misrepresentation by Eliphaz" puts God in even worse light for repeatedly inflicting harm on Job despite Satan's erred prediction.

Comment: @IñakiViggers, "I can't think of a passage where the Bible discredits the Eliphaz's assertions the OP brought up." This is a strawman and shifts the burden of proof. Being that Eliphaz is shown to misrepresent God we have no reason to believe him on things that are not independently verified. Eliphaz says that God puts no trust in his Angels. The OP recognizes that God rightly doesn't trust fallen angels, but is there absolutely no angel 
 or holy one that God trusts? There is no reason to believe this is true.

Comment: @IñakiViggers You are ignoring the source of Eliphaz's words in 15:15 -- they came from the apparition that spoke to him in 4:18. I addressed who it was that manifested to Eliphaz [here](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/50278/10955). You, of course, will make up your own mind. BTW, in 15:15 Eliphaz puts his own spin on the words of the apparition.

Comment: @Austin "*This is a strawman and shifts the burden of proof.*" I am not supposed to prove *your* insinuation that the Bible discredits Eliphaz. Again, 2:3 even supports Eliphaz's statement at 4:18. "*is there absolutely no angel or holy one that God trusts? There is no reason to believe this is true.*" I agree with you on that. As pointed out in the 2nd paragraph of my answer, "*God actually trusted Satan at least twice*" for purposes of inflicting harm on Job.

Comment: @enegue "*I addressed who it was that manifested to Eliphaz*". You only *speculated* that it was Satan, but that suggestion is conclusory and devoid of support in the text. It falls short of establishing that 42:7 refers to Eliphaz's specific statements at 4:18 & 15:15.

Comment: @IñakiViggers, ***"is there absolutely no angel or holy one that God trusts?* There is no reason to believe this is true." I agree with you on that.** Great. Then we should basically be on the same page. **"God actually trusted Satan at least twice" for purposes of inflicting harm on Job.** I don't get that read at all. I understand that God was confident that Job would succeed and Satan lose. I believe God allowed Job to be tested so that Job could be further perfected and elevated.

Comment: @Austin "*I don't get that read at all.*" Had God distrusted Satan, God would not have authorized Satan to repeatedly harm Job. "*I believe God allowed Job to be tested so that Job could be further perfected and elevated.*" As a personal belief it's ok, but there is no hermeneutical basis for that. The Book of Job nowhere indicates that the purpose of the agreement/conspiracy between God and Satan to harm Job was so that "Job could be further perfected and elevated".

Comment: @IñakiViggers I know I'm flogging a dead horse here, but do you believe what the Psalmist says, "*The LORD looked down from heaven upon the children of men, to see if there were any that did understand, and seek God. They are all gone aside, they are all together become filthy: there is none that doeth good, no, not one.*" Job was a sinner, but not in the way his friends accused him. It's pretty clear to me what his issue was, which he repented of in dust and ashes at the end of the story. Do you know what his sin was?

Comment: @enegue "*It's pretty clear to me what his issue was, which he repented of in dust and ashes at the end of the story. Do you know what his sin was?*" Basically you are trying to start a new different controversy about my beliefs, but 1:1 [KJV] very clearly states that Job "*was perfect and upright*" and 1:22 "*In all this Job sinned not*". Job's statement at 42:6 in no way implies that he was the sinner you now purport. Regardless, your attempt is completely irrelevant to the biblical hermeneutics of Eliphaz's statements and the OP's questions.

Comment: @IñakiViggers It's not irrelevant to the foundation of your understanding of the book of Job. You believe there was an "*agreement/conspiracy between God and Satan to harm Job*". You couldn't be more wrong! God rescued Job. The means of rescue was extreme because Job couldn't be reached any other way. You didn't answer my question: Do you know what Job's sin was?

Comment: @enegue "*You couldn't be more wrong!*" It appears that you haven't read 1:12 [KJV] ("*And the Lord said unto Satan, Behold, all that he hath is in thy power*") and 2:6 ("*And the Lord said unto Satan, Behold, he is in thine hand; but save his life*"). These agreements between God and Satan resulted in Job's losses and suffering. "*You didn't answer my question*" I definitely did, just not with something you want to hear. The citations I provided (1:1 and 1:22) debunk the *non sequitur* that Job was a sinner.

Comment: @IñakiViggers Those citations don't debunk the fact that Job REPENTED. God wants you to discover what Job repented of. Can you let go of your misunderstanding of the story to discover what his issue was?

Comment: @enegue "*Those citations don't debunk the fact that Job REPENTED.*" But they certainly debunk your assertion that Job *sinned*. 42:6 does not imply that Job was a sinner. There are relationships where the abuser falsely induces the victim to believe that the victim has to repent about something, but that does not mean the victim did something wrong. "*God wants you to discover what Job repented of.*" That mission and style are way off-topic for this site. Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128601/discussion-between-inaki-viggers-and-enegue).

Answer (score 1):

First, that we are trying to figure out a spiritual truth intelligibly. That will lead nowhere but to error.

Also, the Bible does not say that "God distrusts His angels". The Bible says that "behold, **he put** no trust in His servants, and His angels He charged with folly".

Well, every of God's creation is His servant. Whether "righteous" or "unrighteous". We see God calling a heathen king His servant (Cyrus). And Jesus Himself asserted the position of the Godhead over the fallen man in John 2:24.

But after we rise past this position (old man, servant) we become sons and friends. For this new status, trust is achievable.

I'd like to point out the use of past tenses... **he put**, not the rather present continuous **he put's'** we are trying to unconsciously but truly attach there. The same applies for **and charged** His angels with folly. Past tense. This leads to believe that the angels being referred to here are the folk who left their estate for the sake of the daughters of men and the folk who joined the great deceiver in the ancient mutiny of Zion.

God bless us all!

Comment: Hi CJ, welcome to BH-Stack Exchange, we are glad you are here. Please be sure to take the [site tour](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) and read our [code of conduct](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/conduct). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Why does God have no trust to his angels?

The Book of Job does not provide a portrait of God's mind that is comprehensive or detailed enough to allow identifying God's specific reasons(s) for putting no trust in his angels.

What one can answer, though, is *whether* God's distrust in his angels is epistemologically and factually supported (as per the narrative in chapters 1 & 2). And the answer is in the affirmative, notwithstanding that God's distrust in his angel(s) is notoriously inconsistent: In line with one of the [comments](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/20143/god-and-angels-in-job-418-and-1515?rq=1&newreg=5a27fc050d5d4820a5d8535aa4ce4e2d#comment35492_20143), God actually trusted Satan at least twice to unjustifiably harm Job under pretext of the wager between God and Satan.

God's concept of Job was that of "*a perfect and an upright man*" (Job 1:8, KJV). Satan was given the opportunity to prove that Job's devotion to God is *conditional on profit*. Satan's proposition turned out to be wrong, for "*[i]n all this Job sinned not, nor charged God foolishly*" (1:22) and "*[i]n all this did not Job sin with his lips*" (2:10). Thus, it was epystemologically correct for God to distrust his angel.

(Apropos of --and contrary to-- [the other answer](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/20143/god-and-angels-in-job-418-and-1515/22205#22205), this epystemological accuracy validates Eliphaz's declarations in 4:18 and 15:15, whence one cannot categorically state that Eliphaz's views "are flawed").

> Why are the heavens not pure in God's sight?

Without foreclosing alternative explanations beforehand, the Tanakh might shed light on the latter half of [15:15](https://parabible.com/Job/15):

### וְ֝שָׁמַ֗יִם לֹא־זַכּ֥וּ בְעֵינָֽיו

The וּ appended to זַכּ֥ suggests allusion to *His purity* (זך: pure), whence I posit that the clause could be paraphrased as: *And in His eyes, the heavens are not [at the level of] His purity*.

Thus, rather than labeling the heavens as impure in themselves, the intended meaning of 15:15 might be to expresses God's superiority over any thing (or something) He has created: in this case, the heavens.