# Did Eliphaz see an angel in Job 4:15?

Tags: job

Job 4:15 New International Version

> A **spirit** glided past my face, and the hair on my body stood on end.

Did Eliphaz see a good or a bad angel here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I see the Hebrew of Job 4:15-16,

> *<sup>15</sup>Then, a spirit passed before my face;
>
> The hair of my flesh stood up;
>
> <sup>16</sup>It paused, but I could not discern its appearance;
>
> The form before my eyes *was* silent... then, I heard a voice:*

Details: (click to enlarge)
[image]

If verse 15 stood alone, Eliphaz would likely be using רוּחַ ([rûach](https://www.studylight.org/lexicons/hebrew/hwview.cgi?n=7307)) to describe a wind. However, in verse 16 the narrative records him saying, יַעֲמֹ֤ד, i.e. "***HE/IT** stood still/paused*", and וְֽלֹא אַכִּ֬יר מַרְאֵ֗הוּ, i.e. "*but I could not discern **HIS/ITS** appearance*". Eliphaz is "personifying something" that he could not clearly make out.

Further, the narrative continues with Eliphaz adding, תְּ֭מוּנָה ([temûnâh](https://www.studylight.org/lexicons/hebrew/hwview.cgi?n=8544)), the "*form*", לְנֶ֣גֶד עֵינָ֑י, "*to before (before-ward) of my eyes*", was "*silent*", i.e. Eliphaz could see a shape in front of him that made no sound.

There can be no doubt that Eliphaz was witness to "an obscure form" that would be better described as "a spirit" rather than "a wind". Whether he was awake when the encounter took place is not certain, but since he prefaces it with,

> *<sup>12</sup>Now a thing was secretly brought to me, and mine ear received a little thereof. <sup>13</sup>In thoughts from the visions of the night, when deep sleep falleth on men,*
> <sub>`Job 4:12-13 (KJV)`</sub>

... it can safely be assumed that Eliphaz thought it was a dream.

In regard to "who" it was that visited him, the words that Eliphaz hears indicate to me that it was none other than Satan himself:

> *<sup>17</sup>Shall mortal man be more just than God? shall a man be more pure than his maker? <sup>18</sup>Behold, he put no trust in his servants; and his angels he charged with folly: <sup>19</sup>How much less in them that dwell in houses of clay...*
> <sub>`Job 4:17-19 (KJV)`</sub>

What other angel is likely to say of God, "*he put no trust in his servants*" and "*his angels he charged with folly*"? That this visitor is proud and considers man as inferior, is testified to by his view that, if God were to put no trust in his servants and charge his angels with error, "*HOW MUCH MORE will he charge with error those who dwell in houses of clay.*"

Comment: This answer is educative up until, out of nowhere, it forces the assertion that the visitor was Satan. The premise that "*this visitor is proud and considers man as inferior*" prompts assessing how (if at all) it withstands 1:6 and 2:1 [KJV] ("*the sons of God came to present themselves before the Lord, and Satan came also among them*") given that hitherto there had been no interaction between man and the god. The attempt to rank between the god's servants/angels and "*those who dwell in houses of clay*" is irrelevant to the OP's question.

Answer (score 1):

The passage is deliberately vague.  It is impossible to know whether:

- Eliphaz is simply experiencing a vivid dream/vision, or,
- Eliphaz is actually being visited by an angel or spirit being

Ellicott notes that:

> It is vain to argue from this passage that spiritual essences are
> capable of being seen by the bodily eye, because, first of all, the
> language is highly figurative and poetical, and because, secondly,
> every one understands that a spiritual manifestation can be made only
> to the spirit. The notion, therefore, of seeing a spirit is absurd in
> itself, because it involves the idea of seeing the invisible; but it
> is conceivable that the perceptions of the inner spirit may be so
> vivid as to assume the character of outward manifestations.

Barnes has a similar idea:

> Then a spirit passed before my face - He does not intimate whether it
> was the spirit of a man, or an angel who thus appeared. The belief in
> such apparitions was common in the early ages, and indeed has
> prevailed at all times. No one can demonstrate that God could not
> communicate his will in such a manner as this, or by a messenger
> deputed from his immediate presence to impart valuable truth to
> people.

The Pulpit commentary gives more detail:

> Then a spirit passed before my face. It has been argued (Rosenmuller)
> that "a breath of air," and not "a spirit," is intended; but, in that
> ease, how are we to understand the expressions in the following verse:
> "it stood still," "the form thereof," "an image"? A breath of air, the
> very essence of which is to be in motion, cannot stand still, nor has
> it any "form," "appearance," or "imago." Granted that the Hebrew ruakh
> (רוח) may mean - like the Greek πνεῦμα, and the Latin spiritus -
> either an actual spirit, or a breath, a wind, it follows that, in
> every place where it occurs, we must judge by the context which is
> meant. Here certainly the context points to an actual living spirit,
> as what Eliphaz intended. Whether a spirit really appeared to him is a
> separate question. The whole may have been a vision; but certainly the
> impression left on Eliphaz was that he had had a communication from
> the spirit-world. The hair of my flesh stood up. Not the hair of his
> head only, but every hair on his whole body, stiffened, bristled, and
> rose up on end in horror (see the comment on ver. 14).

Answer (score 0):

He "saw a ghost". In other words he saw someone that was reported to be dead but was very much alive.

He is hinting to Job (Jacob) that his son (Joseph) is still alive and in Egypt.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it was satan the devil because at this point, Job was being tested and satan was trying to use every available channel to provoke and discourage him, first through his wife (curse God and die) and now through his friends. We know that at the end, God wasn't happy with those same friends and had even issued certain judgement against them that warranted Job having to pray for them. This was definitely not a spirit from God.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).